# How to start an incremental crawl of a search scope from code in SharePoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can this be done?  I haven't found anything out there that shows a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A search scope can not be crawled. A search scope may include or exclude a content source  which is actually crawled.

To start a crawl on a content source use the following code:

```
SearchServiceApplicationProxy proxy = SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext.Current);
Guid appId = ssap.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo().SearchServiceApplicationId;
SearchServiceApplication app = SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(appId);
Content content = new Content(app)

ContentSource cs = content.ContentSources["<content source name>"];
cs.StartIncrementalCrawl();
// check on cs.CrawlStatus if finished
```