# Programmatically start crawling a given content source in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to programmatically start crawling a given content source (say a file share) through Sharepoint API or any other means?

Comment: I found this question if anyone else is looking for the same. But I don't understand how to adopt it to use a file share instead of a business data content source. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191544/create-sharepoint-2010-search-content-source-that-uses-a-bdc-via-powershell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393766/how-to-start-an-incremental-crawl-of-a-search-scope-from-code-in-sharepoint

Comment: Thanks Rob! I'll check this tomorrow and post the results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Rob's comment above I found this to be helpful. Following is the C# code I did.

The code in the link throws an error on SPServiceContext.Current if you're building a console app. So the first step and the GetContext() method are specific to that situation.

```
SPSite mySite = new SPSite("http://localhost");
                SearchServiceApplicationProxy proxy = (SearchServiceApplicationProxy)SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext.GetContext(mySite));                     Guid appId = proxy.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo().SearchServiceApplicationId;

                //Console.WriteLine("AppID : " + appId.ToString());

                SearchServiceApplication app = SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(appId);
                Content content = new Content(app);

                ContentSourceCollection cs = content.ContentSources;
                Console.WriteLine("Name\tId\tCrawlCompleted");
                foreach (ContentSource csi in cs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(csi.Name + "\t" + csi.Id + "\t" + csi.CrawlCompleted);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Starting full crawl....");

                ContentSource css = content.ContentSources["source name"]; //csi.Name within square brackets
                css.StartFullCrawl();

                Console.WriteLine("Full crawl on source name started...");
```

Be sure to adjust the build target platform in the Project Properties with the Sharepoint installation. Otherwise SpSite will not be created.